# Wrong std and mean values then expected

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `X` with 3 columns. For the porous of the question `X=randn(5,3)`.
I want to normalize the columns of `X` S.T. each column will have a `0` mean and a `1` std. I was using the following code:

```
X=(X-mean(X))./std(X);
```

I am getting an std of `1`. My mean, however, is a very small value close to `0` but not essential `0`. I tried playing a bit with the numbers to find an explanation:

```
X=1:15;
X=reshape(X,[5 3]);
mean(X-mean(X));
```

Which gives me `0` value for each column.

```
X=1:15;
X=reshape(X,[5 3]);
mean((X-mean(X))./std(X));
```

Which does not. But 0/anything is still 0. what am I missing?

- Why am I not getting `0` values?
- Are the values I am getting good enough for a pre-clustering algorithm normalization?

Comment: Are you sure you've written the code you're using correctly? Copying what you've got gives a matrix mismatch error... Mean returns the average for each row, so `X-mean(X)` is not valid...

Comment: Check if there are local files implementing `mean` and `std` functions.

Comment: @Philip I am sure about the code. I just copy and pasted to check. `mean(X)` gives a row with the mean for each column. `X-mean(X)` subtracts the mean of each column from each column.

Comment: @Rotem do you mean other then the original matlab implantation? I am sure there are none.

Comment: The code: `X=1:15;X=reshape(X,[5 3]);mean(X-mean(X));` gives an error. Are you sure you are using Matlab? Use `clear all`, and check again.

Comment: @Rotem, just run it again (third time), copy paste from the post. I am getting no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that does what I think you're trying to do... you need to replicate the matrix because X-mean(X) isn't valid (if you're using the standard implementation)-- you can't subtract a 1x3 from a 5x3.

```
r = 5; c = 3;
X=randn(r,c);
Xm=repmat(mean(X),r,1);
Xstd = repmat(std(X),r,1);
Xn = (X-Xm)./Xstd;
mean(Xn)
std(Xn)
```

For me this prints out

```
ans =

  1.0e-16 *

 -0.6661         0    0.4441


ans =

  1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Which seems like exactly what you're looking for... note the 1e-16 multiplier on the mean values... this is essentially 0, with some floating point error.

Comment: I can and have subtract a 1x3 from a 5x3 (I have tested vry carfully for the correct values). I am getting the same values you are getting with my code. Maybe it is a derivative of MATLAB versions difference.In any case, my question was referring to your 'essentially 0' comment. Can you kindly elaborate on why are we not getting definite zeros?

Comment: Hm, you're definitely using a non-standard implementation if that works for you... in any case, floating point numbers are not infinitely precise. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) for elaboration. Or just google "floating point arithmetic error"

Comment: The difference might be due to one of the 'computer vision' expectations? I know for sure I\no one else have never implemented no `mean()` or subtraction function on this mu chine.

Comment: Oh, apparently matlab 2016b adds the capability to subtract compatible sizes--I'm still on 2015!